# Stack won't build because of ippicv?

Tags: opencv, haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

So I have a project that was initially built using cabal. I'd like to make it compatible with stack. I issue stack init. I run `stack build` and get

```
setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3: Missing dependency on a foreign
library:
* Missing C library: ippicv
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

I'm running ubuntu 15.10. Opencv  3.1.0 is fully installed on my machine. I can even run the sample's but for some reason I get this error. Does anyone know why?

Comment: How is `ippicv` referenced in the `.cabal` file? Is there `pkgconfig-depends:` line in the cabal file?

Comment: @ErikR it's referenced in a nix package actually.

Comment: Do you have the "-dev" version of the library?

Comment: @Eric figured it out. Well, in my case specifically, I moved -lippicv to private in opencv.pc.